# angular how to set services in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am trying to set http request data in one controller and let the data be used in multiple controller. I have something like

My services

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Product','$q',
    function(Product, $q) {
        var products, targetProduct;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Product.query({
            Id: 123
            }, function(products) {
                targetProduct = products[0];
                deferred.resolve(products);
        })

        var getTargetProduct = function() {
            var deferredtwo = $q.defer();

            // return deferredtwo.promise;
            deferred.promise.then(function(){
                deferredtwo.resolve(targetProduct);
            })
            return deferredtwo.promise;
        }

        var setTargetProduct = function(targetProduct) {
                targetProduct = targetProduct
        }

        return {
            setTargetProduct: setTargetProduct,
            getTargetProduct: getTargetProduct,
            productPromise : deferred.promise
        };
    }
]);
```

nav controller

```
  testService.productPromise.then(function(products){
            $scope.products= products;
             $scope.targetProduct = products[0];
   })
  //when user click the project  ng-click = setTargetProduct(product);
  $scope.setTargetProduct = function(targetProduct) {
         testService.setTargetProduct(targetProduct)
   }
```

product detail controller

```
      testService.getTargetProduct().then(function(targetProduct) {
           // works when page first loads
           // but I don't know how to update the targetProduct when user select different             
           //targetProduct which means they trigger setTargetProduct() method
           $scope.targetProduct = targetProduct; 
      })
```

As I stated above, I am not sure how to update the `targetProduct` in product detail controller when user pick another `targetProduct`. Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about passing in a callback to the service from the product controller that is raised whenever the product is set?

Comment: @dustmouse that sounds like a good idea. Could you provide some examples? Thanks!

Comment: @FlyingCat, what is `testService.classPromise` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of style, the function `getTargetProduct` doesn't need all this boilerplate code with promises. You want to return a simple promise wrapping your local data `targetProduct`. The function can be much cleaner :

```
var getTargetProduct = function() {
    return $q.when(targetProduct);
}
```

*Note: In the following, for convenience purpose, I will refer to your service `testService` by the name `productService`, and I will refer to your controller `navController` by the name `ProductController`*

The controller `NavController` (gets the products as follows :

```
productService.getProducts().then(function(products) {
    $scope.products = products;
}
```

When the user sets a *target product* (unchanged) :

```
$scope.setTargetProduct = function(targetProduct) {
   testService.setTargetProduct(targetProduct)
}
```

***Solution 1: nested controllers***

If `ProductDetailController` is a nested controller of `ProductController`, the data `targetProduct` is shared without any logic from your part.

***Solution 2: controllers not linked by a parent-child relationship***

If the two controllers are not linked by a parent-child relationship, you can use `$broadcast` for broadcasting an *updateTargetProduct* event, and `$on` for handling that event.

In the controller from which we set the target product, we will find :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('updateTargetProduct', targetProduct);
```

Note : `$broadcast` will broadcast the event from the rootscope down to the child scopes.

And in *ProductDetailController*, we will listen for this event :

```
$scope.$on('updateTargetProduct', function(event, data) {
    // play with the received data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will need solution two as my controllers are not linked. I know I can use rootscope approach but I try not to because I hate to pollute rootscope. Is there anyway I can do it via productService only? Thanks for your help. +1

Comment: Like you, I hate polluting rootscope. Here we are not storing the `targetProduct` in the rootscope, we are broadcasting an event that will travel from the rootscope down to the childs.

Comment: is it a better practice than using services? i mean, I am trying to use it via productservice to do everything. Not sure if it's possible though

Comment: Well for this use case I do not see any bad practice about sending the data via a message. Such a use case could involve updating a cart widget, of which the controller is not related with the other one. As for your question *"Is there anyway I can do it via productService only"*, the answer is yes, some people would store the data in a property of the service (which is a singleton), and reference that property from both controllers. However that would make the service statefull, and I find that approach less clean.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your situation is not same as like me , but i made a service for my own $http call

```
var myService = angular.module('apix',[]);

myService.service('api',function( $http ){

        this.http = function( method , path , data ){

            return $http({
                method: method,
                url: path,
                headers: {                          
                    'Content-Type' :  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data : jQuery.param(data)
            }); 




        }

});
```

and used to call this as like

```
 api.http('POST','your_path', data).success(function(result){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('ipFactory', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var service = {
      getIp: function() {
        return $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/', {
            cache: true
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            return data.data.ip;
          });
      }
    }

    return service;
  }
])

.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', 'ipFactory',
  function($scope, ipFactory) {
    ipFactory.getIp()
      .then(function(ip) {
        $scope.ipAddress = ip;
      });
  }
])

.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', 'ipFactory',
  function($scope, ipFactory) {
    ipFactory.getIp()
      .then(function(ip) {
        $scope.ipAddress = ip;
      });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
    {{ipAddress}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
    {{ipAddress}}
  </div>
</body>
```